# Selecting random rows and order by ID

Tags: mysql

Here is the code I tried to select 6 random entries from database and it works fine.

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM tbl_all_ads 
      WHERE status='online' 
      AND brand='$brand' 
      ORDER BY RAND()  
      LIMIT 6";
```

But I need these randomly select values to order by id, ASC or DESC order. Here id,  is auto increment integer.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM tbl_all_ads 
                    WHERE status='online' 
                    AND brand='$brand' 
                    ORDER BY RAND()  
                    LIMIT 6
             ) as t1  ORDER BY id ASC ;
```

Comment: Great !!! It's working. Thank you so much :)